# CSS border colour and radius issues on links

Tags: html, css

I am having two issues with the following styled link.

1. There is a small, white border being displayed on the left and right sides of link on hover.
2. The `::before` border radius is being applied during the transition on Webkit browsers. All other browsers are applying it before the transition.

I have tried adjusting z indexes for various elements, but this has had no effect on the small, white border issue.

I have tried applying border radius to `a::before` and `a:hover::before` to see if that would fix the issue in Webkit browsers, but no luck.

Any ideas on why these CSS issues are occurring?

```css
body {
  background-color: #1A1A1A;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.cta {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-family: "Barlow", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -0.0225rem;
  color: #D61E15;
}

.cta--pill {
  padding: 0.625rem 1rem 0.625rem 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0.03125rem solid #E6E6E6;
  border-radius: 1.3125rem;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.cta--pill::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #D61E15;
  border: 0.03125rem solid #D61E15;
  border-radius: 1.3125rem;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.cta--pill .cta-text {
  padding-right: 2.25rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.cta--pill .cta-arrow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 1.75rem;
  height: 1.75rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4375rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #D61E15;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(176, 25, 17, 0.41);
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 0.03125rem solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.cta--pill:hover {
  border-color: #D61E15;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(176, 25, 17, 0.41);
  color: #fff;
}

.cta--pill:hover::before {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<a class="cta cta--pill cta--no-shadow" href="#" title="View all services">
  <span class="cta-text">All Services</span>
  <span class="cta-arrow">
      <svg role="img" class="arrow arrow--right" width="14" height="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M6.02 1.183l.658-.658a.708.708 0 0 1 1.004 0l5.761 5.758a.708.708 0 0 1 0 1.004l-5.76 5.761a.708.708 0 0 1-1.005 0l-.658-.658a.712.712 0 0 1 .012-1.016l3.57-3.402H1.087a.71.71 0 0 1-.711-.711v-.949a.71.71 0 0 1 .71-.711h8.518L6.032 2.199a.707.707 0 0 1-.012-1.016z" fill="#FFF"></path>
    </svg>
  </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also slide background-gradients via background-position.

possible example:

```css
body {
  background-color: #1A1A1A;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.cta {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-family: "Barlow", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -0.0225rem;
  color: #D61E15;
}

.cta--pill {
  padding: 0.625rem 1rem 0.625rem 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 75% 50%, #D61E15 1.3rem, transparent 1.35rem), linear-gradient(0, #D61E15, #D61E15);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  background-position: 180% 50%, 220% 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0.03125rem solid #E6E6E6;
  border-radius: 1.3125rem;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.cta--pill:hover {
  background-position: 50% 50%, 100% 0;
}

.cta--pill .cta-text {
  padding-right: 2.25rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.cta--pill .cta-arrow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 1.75rem;
  height: 1.75rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4375rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #D61E15;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(176, 25, 17, 0.41);
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 0.03125rem solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.cta--pill:hover {
  border-color: #D61E15;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(176, 25, 17, 0.41);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<a class="cta cta--pill cta--no-shadow" href="#" title="View all services">
  <span class="cta-text">All Services</span>
  <span class="cta-arrow">
      <svg role="img" class="arrow arrow--right" width="14" height="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M6.02 1.183l.658-.658a.708.708 0 0 1 1.004 0l5.761 5.758a.708.708 0 0 1 0 1.004l-5.76 5.761a.708.708 0 0 1-1.005 0l-.658-.658a.712.712 0 0 1 .012-1.016l3.57-3.402H1.087a.71.71 0 0 1-.711-.711v-.949a.71.71 0 0 1 .71-.711h8.518L6.032 2.199a.707.707 0 0 1-.012-1.016z" fill="#FFF"></path>
    </svg>
  </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a negative inset to the `::before` selector.

```css
body {
  background-color: #1A1A1A;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.cta {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-family: "Barlow", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -0.0225rem;
  color: #D61E15;
}

.cta--pill {
  padding: 0.625rem 1rem 0.625rem 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0.03125rem solid #E6E6E6;
  border-radius: 1.3125rem;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.cta--pill::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #D61E15;
  border: 0.03125rem solid #D61E15;
  border-radius: 1.3125rem;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.cta--pill .cta-text {
  padding-right: 2.25rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.cta--pill .cta-arrow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 1.75rem;
  height: 1.75rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4375rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #D61E15;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(176, 25, 17, 0.41);
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 0.03125rem solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.cta--pill:hover {
  border-color: #D61E15;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(176, 25, 17, 0.41);
  color: #fff;
}

.cta--pill:hover::before {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<a class="cta cta--pill cta--no-shadow" href="#" title="View all services">
  <span class="cta-text">All Services</span>
  <span class="cta-arrow">
      <svg role="img" class="arrow arrow--right" width="14" height="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M6.02 1.183l.658-.658a.708.708 0 0 1 1.004 0l5.761 5.758a.708.708 0 0 1 0 1.004l-5.76 5.761a.708.708 0 0 1-1.005 0l-.658-.658a.712.712 0 0 1 .012-1.016l3.57-3.402H1.087a.71.71 0 0 1-.711-.711v-.949a.71.71 0 0 1 .71-.711h8.518L6.032 2.199a.707.707 0 0 1-.012-1.016z" fill="#FFF"></path>
    </svg>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: The same issue persists during the transition

Comment: @RobbertLokhorst The negative inset reduces the thickness, but does not completely remove the border artifact.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `background-color: #D61E15;` inside `.cta--pill:hover` will solve your white border problem.

```css
body {
  background-color: #1A1A1A;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.cta {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-family: "Barlow", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -0.0225rem;
  color: #D61E15;
}

.cta--pill {
  padding: 0.625rem 1rem 0.625rem 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0.03125rem solid #E6E6E6;
  border-radius: 1.3125rem;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.cta--pill::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #D61E15;
  border: 0.03125rem solid #D61E15;
  border-radius: 1.3125rem;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.cta--pill .cta-text {
  padding-right: 2.25rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.cta--pill .cta-arrow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 1.75rem;
  height: 1.75rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4375rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #D61E15;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(176, 25, 17, 0.41);
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 0.03125rem solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.cta--pill:hover {
  border-color: #D61E15;
  background-color: #D61E15;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(176, 25, 17, 0.41);
  color: #fff;
}

.cta--pill:hover::before {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<a class="cta cta--pill cta--no-shadow" href="#" title="View all services">
  <span class="cta-text">All Services</span>
  <span class="cta-arrow">
      <svg role="img" class="arrow arrow--right" width="14" height="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M6.02 1.183l.658-.658a.708.708 0 0 1 1.004 0l5.761 5.758a.708.708 0 0 1 0 1.004l-5.76 5.761a.708.708 0 0 1-1.005 0l-.658-.658a.712.712 0 0 1 .012-1.016l3.57-3.402H1.087a.71.71 0 0 1-.711-.711v-.949a.71.71 0 0 1 .71-.711h8.518L6.032 2.199a.707.707 0 0 1-.012-1.016z" fill="#FFF"></path>
    </svg>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: I don't think so, This will cause the issues with animation which OP does not want

Comment: Post the snippet then?

Comment: The same issue persists during the transition

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I only meant to answer white borders on both ends.